# Метод простой перестановки

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list, перестановка

Как зациклить функцию на столько раз, сколько символов в переменной "key"?

Дан следующий код, где две функции: одна шифрует, другая расшифровывает. Функция "cryp" зашифровывает слово. Функция "encryp" должна расшифровывать, но она ещё не готова. Такая идея: сделать в функции "encryp" цикл, который будет использовать внутри себя функцию "cryp" столько раз, сколько символов в переменной "key" минус один.

Что делает функция "cryp":
Вход:
cif
246531
абсолютность
Выход:
боюлсансьтот

Что должна делать функция "encryp":
Вход:
decif
246531
боюлсансьтот
Выход:
абсолютность

Внутри цикла:
key = 246531
длина key = 6, значит нужно 5 циклов

При первом цикле вывод - 'оласюбсттоьн',
При втором - 'лсбюаотоньтс',
При третьем - 'сюоаблоьстнт',
При четвёртом - 'юалбосьттнсо',
При пятом - 'абсолютность' (Это идёт на выход)

```
print("Будем шифровать или расшифровывать? cif/decif") #print cif for encryption or decif for decryption
cipher=input()
print("Введите, пожалуйста, ключ: ") #print some int number
key=input()
print("Введите, пожалуйста, ваше предложение: ") #print your sentence for en\decryption
text=input()

def cryp(key, text):
    key_length = len(key)          #отсюда начинается перечисление всего того, что будет задействовано
    q = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    x = str()
    ret = []
    p = len(text)//len(key)
    if len(text)%len(key) != 0:
        p=p+1
    matrix = [[0 for x in range(key_length)] for y in range(p)]           #до этого места
    for x in text:              #отсюда идет шифровка
        matrix[i][j] = x
        j = j+1
        if j%key_length == 0:
            j=0
            i=i+1
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while q != p:
        for n in key:
            ret += matrix[q][(int(n))-1]
        q=q+1                     #до этого места
    sret = ''.join(ret)           #здесь перевод массива в строку
    return sret
    
def encryp(key, text):
    key_length = len(key)           #отсюда начинается перечисление всего того, что будет задействовано
    q = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    l = 0
    x = str()
    ret = []
    p = len(text)//len(key)
    if len(text)%len(key) != 0:
        p=p+1
    matrix = [[0 for x in range(key_length)] for y in range(p)]
    txt = text                       #до этого места
    while l != key_length:
        for x in txt:
            matrix[i][j] = x
            j = j+1
            if j%key_length == 0:
                j=0
                i=i+1
        i = 0
        j = 0
        while q != p:
            for n in key:
                ret += matrix[q][(int(n))-1]
            q=q+1
        sret = ''.join(ret)
        txt = sret
        l=l+1
        sret = None
    sret = txt
    return sret

if cipher == "cif":
    print(cryp(key, text))
elif cipher == "decif":
    print(encryp(key, text))
else:
    print("Прошу прощения, но, видимо, где-то ошибка. Надеюсь, вы правильно всё написали. Приношу извинения за сбой!")
#Here is an apology for the fact that you or the program made a mistake somewhere
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам

```
def encryp(key, text):
    key_length = len(key)
    if (key_length % 2) == 1:
        l = 2
    else:
        l = 1
    while l != key_length:
        txt = cryp(key, text)
        l=l+1
        text = txt
    return txt
```